# My QT static builds run out of memory on other systems

Tags: qt, memory, memory-management

When I build my application statically, it comes out to just over 5Mb, so it's a small, simple program. However, any system that has under 3Gb of ram can't run the program, saying there's not enough memory. There is nothing very memory intensive in the program, and I did nothing to allocate memory specifically. Any thoughts on whats causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the static build. I first got it to work by exporting from the visual studio plugin, and then I rebuilt the SDK and program again, and everything worked fine from QT creator.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that less the 1Mb built code can easilly fill the 10GB memory. Make sure that your code does not use redundant memory.

Comment: I did nothing at all to allocate memory inside the program, so unless there's some hidden thing in the build process or something, I don't think that's the issue...

Comment: May be you could post some code or compile with another compiler or on another OS? Just it is impossible to guess your problem.

Comment: It compiles and runs in QT creator in debug or release mode on any system I've tried. When I build a static app on mac, everything works fine, no memory issues. I can't post the code, because I'm writing the program for work.

Comment: Hey may be you could debug and after each line look after memory? Did you try? You could find the line that couses the problem (or lines???).

Comment: The program doesn't use much memory on any system while in debug mode, and the static build doesn't either on a system with >3Gb RAM, it uses about 17k.

Comment: Did you wrote a virus? Quite good virus for computers with less then 3Gb RAM!! :) 

Sorry, I have no idea!